# Bootstrap 4 navbar collapse correct but not able to expand

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm trying out the navbar collapse. I'm able to get it collapse correctly, but it is not expanding when clicked on it.

I've tried all the solutions that I can find:

1. Make sure that Jquery is before Bootstrap
2. Used different CDN links for Jquery
3. Included popper.js CDN

Below are my codes

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbarNav">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
            </a>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Please help as I have been stuck for some time and still not able to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed `#` in `data-target="#navbarNav"` use this

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```